# progress dialog in main activity's onCreate not shown

Tags: android, dialog, progressdialog, oncreate

After the splash screen, it takes about 6 sec to load onCreate contents in the Main activity. So I want to show a progress dialog while loading and here's what I did:

```
import ...

private ProgressDialog mainProgress;

public void onCreate(Bundle davedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    mProgress = new ProgressDialog (Main.this);
    mProgress.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
    mProgress.setMessage("Loading... please wait");
    mProgress.setIndeterminate(false);
    mProgress.setMax(100);
    mProgress.setProgress(0);
    mProgress.show();

    ---some code---

    mProgress.setProgress(50);

    ---some code---

    mProgress.setProgress(100);
    mProgress.dismiss();
}
```

and it doesn't work... the screen stays black for 5-6 sec and then load the main layout. I dont know which part I did wrong :*(

Comment: Whatever you are doing in `---some code---` is blocking the UI thread. Consider using an `AsyncTask` instead. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do start your busy code in an other thread (than the UI thread).
In your activity create the ProgressDialog and close it in the thread

```
mProgress = new ProgressDialog (Main.this);

Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // code that needs 6 seconds for execution

        // after finishing, close the progress bar
        mProgress.dismiss();
    }
};

new Thread(runnable).start();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're doing everything on the UI thread, thus blocking it.

You should do all your heavy-lifting in a separate thread and update the progress dialog through that